# Using mongodb's $nin together with and

Tags: mongodb

I have an app for organizing hackathon events and this is the mongodb schema

```
{
    "_id": "cZpRg4Qa8JPRAJojE",
    "lat": "-1.981388262628872",
    "lng": "36.29487934112549",
    "eventownernumber": "0800123456",
    "eventownernames": "Kraufe",
    "eventtitle": "first test",
    "eventtime": "05:02",
    "invited": "0",
    "eventduration": "5",
    "eventtype": "private",
    "eventcategory": "hackathon",
    "eventstatus": "11",
    "eventoriginalid": "0",
    "eventjoinernumber": "0",
    "eventjoinernames": "0",
    "eventjoindate": "0",
    "eventleavedate": "0",
    "createdAt": {
        "$date": "2016-10-27T16:33:57.365Z"
    }
}
```

I am displaying the hackathon events on a map.

I want to display the events using this criteria.Users signup using their telephone numbers.

**

> 1. **Show all events one has been invited to**
> 2. **Show all events i have created**
> 3. **Show all public events where my number is not one of them(leave out public events created by myself)**

**

This is the query i have written

```
Events.find({
    {eventownernumber: '0800123456',eventstatus:11 },
    {invited:'0800123456',eventstatus:11},
    {eventtype:'public',eventownernumber:{$nin:['0800123456']},eventstatus:11 }
    });
```

In `eventstatus:11` , `11` represents active hackathon events.

When i run my query, i get unexpected character error(error points to one of my query lines);

How should i correct my query?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, if one of the conditions pass, you want to display the event. So you could try using the [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/or/) operator:

```
Events.find({
    $or: [
      {eventownernumber: '0800123456',eventstatus:11 },
      {invited:'0800123456',eventstatus:11},
      {eventtype:'public',eventownernumber:{$ne:'0800123456'},eventstatus:11 }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Indeed. I was just thinking of a way to do an $or. Why not use $nin instead of $ne?

Comment: $nin is for multiple $ne.